# Is there a way to generate appsettings.json sections from the bound "settings" class?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, appsettings

I'm using strongly typed settings in my .NET 6 Project.

I'm binding the appSettings  via Hostbuilder's

```
.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                        {
                            services.Configure<Settings.Settings>(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection(Settings.Settings.SectionName));
```

I am looking for a way to automatically generate either:

1. The Json section in appsettings.json (or any other json) from my Settings.cs File or
2. The Settings.cs from a json section.

Is there any way I could do this ? Or any other way that is smarter than copy-pasting the Settings.cs' Properties into the Json and editing ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. #1 makes no sense, and for #2 it looks like you're already creating a DI graph object `IOptions<Settings.Settings>` from the specified configuration section.

Comment: @gunr2171 I want to this in the editor while developing. Not during Runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As regards #2, you could use "Paste JSON as classes" (Edit -> Paste special -> Paste JSON as classes):

1. First copy the section from `appsettings.json`
2. Open a code file and insert the JSON content
3. Adjust to your needs

Comment: This does what I want. Thanks. Any way to make this work for Sections or Entries instead of the whole JSON ?

Comment: @DaQookie just select the parts of the JSON that is relevant. However, some adjustments might be necessary, but it could be useful for large configs.